# Generate form by clicking a button in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubygems

I would like to create a form in ruby on rails such that per entry, the user can enter information about a variable number of items. For each item, they should be able to click a button which generates a form they can fill out, and they should submit only once after filling out multiple forms.

I'm not sure how to do this in rails (or if it's possible)-- I don't know how to generate a form on the same page after clicking a button, especially since I should be able to generate multiple forms in that way. Is there a gem/some other way to achieve this? Sorry if the description is a little unclear or vague, basically I want to create a dynamic form that can be adjusted according to how many items I want.

Comment: is it kind of `add more`  functionality

Comment: multiple forms mean there are multiple submissions. If you want to submit only once after filling out multiple forms, consider using a single form and generating fields instead forms.

Comment: Im not 100% sure what your trying to achieve, maybe look into the wicked gem https://github.com/schneems/wicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is nested form. You can achieve this using the cocoon gem - https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon.
It basically generates controls on the fly and submit all in one atomic action.
Just follow the docs :)